# Ini files only work on my computer. How to create ini files in a directory on another computer?

Tags: game-maker

I am creating a game that requires the use of ini files.

The game works perfectly on my computer.

When I create and executable, the executable even uses the ini files when I am programming/testing the game on the engine.

**Directory where the ini files are located:**

```
D:\Users\BonecoSinforoso\AppData\Local\Brasmotor_1
```

The problem occurs when a person from another computer tries to play. The game does not create any ini files.

Even placing the ini files in the zipped file that I put the game on, it gives an error. Because the ini files don't go to a directory that the game can read.

I would like to know how to make my executable create or move the ini files to a directory where the files can be read.

---

**EDIT 1**

**How do I create the ini files:**

```
ini_open("config.ini");
    arkivoIdioma=ini_read_string("jogoIdioma","arkivoIdioma","");
    dadosNum=ini_read_real("dadosNum","dadosNum",1);
    paradaModo=ini_read_string("paradaModo","modo","automatico");
    paradaPorcAutomatico=ini_read_real("paradaPorcAutomatico","porcentagem",10);
    paradaPorcAviso=ini_read_real("paradaPorcAviso","porcentagem",10);
ini_close();
```

**Searching about, I found something explanatory about the directory:**

> The ini files get created. Probably you are not looking in the right
> place for it. The ini file get created in
> %AppData%/Local/"YourGameNameHere" folder, that's where you'll find
> all the files you save.

BY JM DG.

**LINK:**

https://www.reddit.com/r/gamemaker/comments/5d6pf0/how_do_i_create_a_new_ini_file/

**Error obtained by a user:**

[image]

A little earlier, I made a change to the line of this script. I will wait for this user to test again to see if the error has been resolved.

Comment: Is it always BonecoSinforoso or is it the user's actual username? Is it always D:\Users\BonecoSinforoso\AppData\Local or is it the user's actual local appdata directory? (which you can get by calling SHGetKnownFolderPath with FOLDERID_LocalAppData)

Comment: @user253751 user's actual username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To solve the problem. Just add the ini files to the game's zipped file:**

[image]

**And adapt the opening code of the zip file:**

`ini_open("config.ini");` -> `ini_open(working_directory+"config.ini");`